# What does "how to use a ramp" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Just saw this on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/PalmerReport/status/1272362152838512640).

What does "use a ramp" mean?

[image: origin]

Answer (score 2):

The relevant definition of the ramp is this:

> a sloping surface joining two different levels, as at the entrance or
>   between floors of a building.

The context is this:

After a public speech, Trump was walking down the ramp with the help of an officer. He moved with quite a care and hesitation as if he had difficulty to walk by himself. After the event, people started to suspect that he had a health problem. But Trump immediately denied.

The person wants to make fun of Trump with the fact that he could not walk down the ramp properly.

Check this [youtub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tszIXno2Q8)  to watch how he descended the ramp.